Create an array using item from different array
I need to create a new array of objects with 12 item (months & value) on it but it must check if the month exist on other array. If it exist it will push onto the array if not it will have a value of 0
Array to check with
arr1 = 
[
 {
   date: 2024-02,
   value: "100" 
 },
 {
   date: 2024-08,
   person: "200" 
 },
]

What I did
 const getMonthlyAmount = () => {
    let arr = [];

    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      arr1.map((item) => {
        if (arr1.date.slice(0, 5) === i) {
          arr.push(item);
        }
      });
    }
    return arr;
  };

Result I want:
arr = [
 {
   date: 2024-01,
   value: 0
 }, 

 {
   date: 2024-02,
   value: "100" 
 },

... continue

 {
   date: 2024-08,
   person: "200" 
 },

... continue

 {
   date: 2024-12,
   value: 0 
 },
]


You could do it like this:
const getMonthlyAmount = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => {
    const month = (i + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const date = `2024-${month}`;

    const foundItem = arr1.find((entry) => entry.date === date);
    
    return foundItem ? foundItem : { date, value: 0 };
  });
};

This will create the "missing" month and set the value to 0 if they do not exist in the original array you provided.
Demo


const arr1 = [
  {
    date: "2024-02",
    value: "100"
  },
  {
    date: "2024-08",
    person: "200"
  },
];

const getMonthlyAmount = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => {
    const month = (i + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const date = `2024-${month}`;

    const foundItem = arr1.find((entry) => entry.date === date);
    
    return foundItem ? foundItem : { date, value: 0 };
  });
};

console.log(getMonthlyAmount());




In order to do both a) preserve an array-item's structure and also to b) looking it up faster (for a vast amount of items) than by any other array-based find-approach, I would create a Map and date-key based lookup table first.
Then I would create the desired result-array immediately from an array of 12 yet undefined items which I would map with items according to the OP's requirements ... in case an item of a certain date-key does already exist, return this item (or a structured clone of it) or return an item with the defined default structure.


const arr1 = [{
  date: "2024-02",
  value: 100,
}, {
  date: "2024-08",
  person: 200,
}];

const itemLookup = new Map(
  arr1.map(item => [item.date, item])
);

const result = Array
  .from({ length: 12 })
  .map((_, idx) => {
    const date = `2024-${ String(idx + 1).padStart(2, '0') }`;

    return itemLookup.has(date)
    //&& structuredClone(itemLookup.get(date))
      && itemLookup.get(date)
      || { date, value: 0 };
  });

console.log({
  itemLookup: Object.fromEntries(itemLookup.entries()),
});
console.log({ result });
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




You could collect the given date in an object and map a new array by ching the references or taking a new object.


const
    data = [{ date: "2024-02", value: "100" }, { date: "2024-08", person: "200" }],
    references = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.date, o])),
    result = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => {
        const date = `2024-${(i + 1).toString().padStart(2, 0)}`;
        return references[date] || { date, value: 0 };
    });

console.log(result);




Some corrections to your code:

slice(0,5) doesn't extract a month, you could compare a full date
Use Array#find() to find an existing item
Push the found item or a new item if don't exist (use ?? operator)



const data = [{ date: "2024-02", value: "100" }, { date: "2024-08", person: "200" }];
const getMonthlyAmount = () => {
  let arr = [];

  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    const date = `2024-${i.toString().padStart(2, 0)}`;
    arr.push(data.find(item => item.date === date) ?? { date , value: 0 });
  }
  return arr;
};

console.log(getMonthlyAmount());



If you are interested in speed (benchmarked):
` Chrome/125
----------------------------------------------------
Alexander     ■ 1.00x | x1000000 372 373 376 390 448
Carsten         2.09x | x1000000 777 787 788 817 818
Peter           2.82x |  x100000 105 109 109 113 114
Nina Scholz     3.28x |  x100000 122 126 129 130 134
---------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const data = [{ date: "2024-02", value: "100" }, { date: "2024-08", person: "200" }];

// @benchmark Alexander
const getMonthlyAmount = () => {
  let arr = [];

  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    const date = `2024-${i.toString().padStart(2, 0)}`;
    arr.push(data.find(item => item.date === date) ?? { date , value: 0 });
  }
  return arr;
};
// @run
getMonthlyAmount();

// @benchmark Nina Scholz
const references = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.date, o]));
Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => {
    const date = `2024-${(i + 1).toString().padStart(2, 0)}`;
    return references[date] || { date, value: 0 };
});

// @benchmark Carsten
const getMonthlyAmount2 = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => {
    const month = (i + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const date = `2024-${month}`;

    const foundItem = data.find((entry) => entry.date === date);
    
    return foundItem ? foundItem : { date, value: 0 };
  });
};
// @run
getMonthlyAmount2();

// @benchmark Peter
const itemLookup = new Map(
  data.map(item => [item.date, item])
);
Array
  .from({ length: 12 })
  .map((_, idx) => {
    const date = `2024-${ String(idx + 1).padStart(2, '0') }`;

    return itemLookup.has(date)
    //&& structuredClone(itemLookup.get(date))
      && itemLookup.get(date)
      || { date, value: 0 };
  });

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




I don't quite understand the -1 regarding Alexander's answer / approach. For such votes I personally wish for an additional comment. But I also know all the reasons the voting system is as it is. I think Alexander's solution is as good / valid as any of the other ones that received a +1. Thus +1 here too.

@PeterSeliger i guess that's due the benchmark, which like downvoting other solutions based on speed only, but that's also some learning how to write fast JS and i'm not always the first, once you took the 1st place and got an upvote from me
